# Combine array of objects by attribute

Tags: javascript, lodash

Hi there, I'm trying to combine an array of objects and need the end result to be an array of object with one of the attr unique and the other one an array with all the values from the second attr in the original

Array I have:

```
let arr = [
    { 
        name: 'cdd_register', 
        levels: 'read' 
    }, { 
        name: 'cdd_register', 
        levels: 'write' 
    }, { 
        name: 'annual_reports', 
        levels: 'write' 
    }
];
```

And the result I expect is:

```
let result = [
    { 
        name: 'cdd_register', 
        levels: ['read', 'write']
    }, { 
        name: 'annual_reports', 
        levels: 'write' 
    }
];
```

I have this response from the backend

```
data: [{
    id:1
    label: "Administrator"
    name: "admin"
    permissions:{
        data: [{
            id: 4, 
            name: "cdd_register.read", 
            label: "Read access on CDD Register module"
        }, {
            id: 6, 
            name: "cdd_register.write", 
            label: "Write access on CDD Register module"
        }, {
            id: 7, 
            name: "annual_reports.write", 
            label: "Write access on Annual Reports module"
        }]
    }
}]
```

And after this

```
getModules(roles) {
    let modules = [];

    _.forEach(roles, role => {
        _.forEach(role.permissions.data, permission => {
            modules.push(permission);
        })
    });

    return _.uniqBy(modules, 'id').map(module => {
        let moduleArray = module.name.split('.');
            return {
                 name: moduleArray[0],
                 levels: moduleArray[1]
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have the result as it's now but cant figure out the best way (clean) of doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. You need to add the code you've worked on to your question in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, updated with an example of code and response from the server @Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in many different ways. One possible way could be using some functional magic

```js
let arr = [{
  name: 'cdd_register',
  levels: 'read'
}, {
  name: 'cdd_register',
  levels: 'write'
}, {
  name: 'annual_reports',
  levels: 'write'
}];

let result = arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const found = acc.find(y => (x.name == y.name));
  if (!found) {
    acc.push({
      name: x.name,
      levels: arr
        .filter(y => (x.name == y.name))
        .map(z => (z.levels))
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks @ncardeli, that's the solution I was looking for :)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.